# Java and Internet Explorer 9 - not loading first applet

Tags: java, internet-explorer-9, japplet

I have 2 JApplet jars, jar A and jar B. Initially jar A is executed, it does some operations and downloads files to PC that B needs for its operations. When A is finished it executes B. The above works perfectly in the latest versions of Firefox and Safari, but not in IE9. In IE9
A is never shown executing in the browser, instead I get a blank screen for couple of seconds and I am forwarded to B. Also A doesn't perform its operations. Is there anything in IE9 I should be aware of, maybe a security feature or something that could be causing this?

**Update:**
I have just checked this in previous versions of IE and in those versions it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

It may be related to the security settings or third-party software.

First option:

*Click on Tools, then Internet Options.

*Click on the Security tab at the top of the Internet Options window.

*Click on the Custom Level button.

*Scroll down the settings window, and near the bottom you will find an option labelled "Scripting of Java applets".

*Set this to "Enable".

*Click on okay.

Second option: some software like spybot search and blablablah can block unsigned applets. Check that out disabling complements (addins?).